# is using find() in this simple case overkill?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you are caching elements with javascript, which is more efficient?

```
HTML
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>

Javascript:

var parent = $('#parent');
var child = $('#child');
```

or

```
var parent = $('#parent');
var child = $(parent).find('#child');
```

Is one better than the other? Or better practise? I'm writing a lot of code like this, and I am currently using find() to get specific elements of parents that are already cached.

Thanks

Comment: When you use  ids and there are no specific logic needed in selection go with first one. Also second approach can just be `parent.find('#child');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PSL says, as ids, the first is better, but with classes, the second would be faster because then you don't have to search the whole document for `.child` you just have to search within the `#parent`

Also, you can go:

```
var child = parent.find('#child');
```

instead of

```
var child = $(parent).find('#child');
```